# mysql binlog output file is ambiguous?

Tags: mysql, mysqlbinlog, binlog

I use

```
mysqlbinlog -f -v --base64-output=DECODE-ROWS mysql-bin.00001 > res.000001
```

my table has a column is varbinary. So res.000001 like this

```
### UPDATE db.tbl
### WHERE
###   @1=967540772
###   @2='\x10\x00c\x01\x00%...'
### SET
###   @1=967540772
###   @2='\x10\x001\x00\x00,...'
```

I found binlog will convert invisible characters to hex( e.g. `"\n", "\r"`), normal characters will be printed directly( e.g.`"%", "a"`). There is something wrong. If this column is `"\x10"`, binlog will output`"\x10"` (we call case 1), if this column is the character these hex also is `"0x10"`, binlog will output `"\x10"` TOO (we call case 2). So I can not talk the difference between these string.

In case 1, I think binlog should output `"\x10"` to escape backslash. Is this bug of mysql binlog?